# Select distinct on 2 columns, but return all columns from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to select distinct on 2 columns but return all columns?

For example

```
select distinct name, type 
from dbo.Table
```

but return all columns from `dbo.Table`?

I found this solution that works for a single column,

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         [name], [type],
         [col1], [col2], [col3],
         [etc], [dateAdded], [ID],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY dateAdded DESC) rownumber 
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Table]) a 
WHERE
    rownumber = 1;
```

is it possible to do this for multiple columns?

Comment: You can partition by more than 1 column. Just change the partition to name, type.

Comment: As Sean said, use `Partition by name, type` but to be clear that doesnt select distinct row, that select the last one based on `dateAdded`.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and explain how the result is to be obtained.

Comment: for example  table have   2 rows, both rows have same values for `name` and `type` columns, but different values for another columns. How do you imagine result `select distinct on 2 columns but return all columns` ?

Comment: what values would you want from the other columns?...  ok so you just want teh most recent dateadded record from the table per name/type.

Comment: wow I can't believe I didn't try that. Just learned about the partition command. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partition by name and type as below

```
SELECT * from(select 
   [name]
  ,[type]
  ,[col1]
  ,[col2]
  ,[col3]
  ,[etc]
  ,[dateAdded]
  ,[ID]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by name, type order by dateAdded DESC) rownumber from [dbo].[Table]) a where rownumber = 1;
```

Comment: Is is possible to get a bit more explanation? Specially last line is happening a lot.

Comment: For each name it will get new number starting from 1 with dateAdded desc, which means for given name we are getting the latest record